# Is there a way to show the total number of individual messages sent in a Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I use Google Hangouts quite a ridiculous amount and I'd like to know if there's a way to show how many individual messages are sent between users in a Hangout conversation.  Is this at all possible?  If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that at this time is not possible to get a reliable number of posts sent as Google didn't make available as:

- the Hangouts web UI doesn't have a messages counter.
- the Google+ Hangouts API is intended to be used to develop apps to be used with video calls and it doesn't have a class for messages.
- the Hangouts web UI only loads the most recent messages.
- messages could be deleted
- messages could not be recorded if the history is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to count the individual chat messages are sent, unless you want to go through your history and manually count, which is cumbersome.

The closest solution I know if is to view your chat history in your Google Account Dashboard: https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard

The "Gmail" section of this dashboard will provide a summary of all of your Gmail activity, including your chat history.

The chat history summary number is how many chat conversations you've had. I'm not sure how they calculate separate chat sessions between the same two people over time, but it'll give you a rough snapshot.